# Unresolved external symbol on abstract class

Tags: c++

I have a class which looks like this:

```
class Team
{
protected:
    string name_;
    Pixel color_;
    static vector<Team>* teams_;
public:
    string name() { return name_; };
    Pixel color() { return color_; };
    static void setTeams(vector<Team>* t) { teams_ = t; };
    static vector<Team>* teams() { return teams_; };
}
```

It consists of mostly getters/setters.

They are set elsewhere in main like:

```
Team::setTeams(&activeTeams);
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<class Team,class std::allocator<class Team> > * Team::teams_"
```

I suspect its because the `teams_` vector is not initialized, but being an abstract class it should not ever be initialized or its constructor called. What should I do about this?

Comment: I don't see how your class is forced to be _abstract_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a `static` template in your class declaration, you should initialize it on your source (aka `.cpp`) like so.

```
vector* Team::teams_ = new vector<Team>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A member variable with `static` exists [independently from any instances](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static). You must therefore initialize it.

The fact that you class is abstract (which the compiler has, in your case, no way of knowing) doesn’t change a thing.